# What Uri in StructuredQName when creating an ExtensionFunctionDefinition in Java for an xsl

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to create an saxon extension in java for an xsl template. I've copy-pasted the code from a solution we often use to 'take inspiration'.

When i exec the code i receive:

```
2020-11-17 11:26:45,866 ERROR [stderr] XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 58 near {...($data.pwd...}:
2020-11-17 11:26:45,866 ERROR [stderr]    Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named
2020-11-17 11:26:45,866 ERROR [stderr]       {http://com.aaa.bbb.intializer/xsl/extensions}decrypt-rsa()
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is the configuration of the uri inside the overridden method getFunctionQName().

```java
package it.ccc.bbb.xxx.util;

class XSLDecrypt extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition
{
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = XSLDecryptRSA.class.getName();
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);

    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName ()
    {
        return new StructuredQName("aaa", "http://com.aaa.bbb.intializer/xsl/extensions", "decrypt");
    }
```

**What's the correct uri to pass in the constructor?**

In my xsl i put:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:aaa="http://com.aaa.bbb.intializer/xsl/extensions">
   ...
   <Parameter Key="password">
       <xsl:value-of select="aaa:decrypt($data.pwd)"/>
   </Parameter>
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: You've had several suggestions as to what might be wrong. Use the -TJ option on the command line for extra diagnostics when functions can't be located.

Comment: Hello, what command line are your talking about?

Comment: Hi Everyone, how can i close the question? i solved it!

Comment: Just accept your own answer. (Don't delete the question - it may be useful to others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution at the problem is to define the new extension in the configuration. It's explained in [saxonica's documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-full-J).

```java
public class XSLExtensions
{
    private static final ExtensionFunctionDefinition[] xslExtensions;
    
    static
    {
        xslExtensions = new ExtensionFunctionDefinition[] {
                new XSLDecrypt()
        };
    }
    
    public static ExtensionFunctionDefinition[] getExtensions()
    {
        return xslExtensions;
    }
    
    public static void applyTo (net.sf.saxon.Configuration saxonConfig)
    {
        if (xslExtensions != null && xslExtensions.length > 0)
        {
            for(ExtensionFunctionDefinition xslExtension : xslExtensions)
            {
                saxonConfig.registerExtensionFunction(xslExtension);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that applies the given configuration at run time, in this case adding the only extension in my solution: XSLDecrypt.

Given that the method applyTo() had to be called (in runtime), it should exist an entry point where to do it. The product my project is based on doesn't allow me to do that unfortunately, so we opted for a porkaround. :( xD

Bye!